# Is reducing the number of active cores in my pc a good idea considering heat and battery troubles?

Tags: processor, heat-sink, battery-life

## [**MOVED TO SUPERUSER STACKEXCHANGE**](https://superuser.com/questions/1118771/is-reducing-the-number-of-active-cores-in-my-pc-a-good-idea-considering-heat-and)

---

I have a HP Pavillion dv6 laptop for about 6 years now, but I have always had heat (the computer now and then "freezes" because of over-heating, even when I am running no heavy processes) and battery (I am not able to watch a full movie with only the battery) troubles.

I suspect that the main problem is in the processor (Intel Core i7 720QM / 1.6 GHz) which consumes too much power and therefore drains battery and overheats at the same time. I read that it is possible to reduce the number of active cores in Windows with msconfig; is this a good idea considering my problem? How will it affect my working experience? Will it reduce heat and increase battery life? Will it reduce performance considerably?

Are there other, and better solutions you would suggest (such as a laptop stand with active cooler, other OS, ...)?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) considering their scope. You are not searching for a new product, you want technical support. :) Therefore I'll flag this question as off-topic.